# undefined method `category_documentations_path' in Rails. My routes have comments instead of documentations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-forms

I try do to a nested form, and when I load the form (/categories/show.html.haml), I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in Categories#show

Showing /home/cederic/rails/mordus/app/views/categories/show.html.haml where line #6 raised:

undefined method `category_documentations_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007fead8742870>:0x00007fead8881038>
Did you mean?  category_comments_path
```

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

    resources :categories do
        resources :documentations
    end

    get 'pages/accueil'

    root 'pages#accueil'
end
```

The output of "rails routes" command:

```
refix Verb   URI Pattern                                          Controller#Action
    category_comments GET    /categories/:category_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                      POST   /categories/:category_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_category_comment GET    /categories/:category_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_category_comment GET    /categories/:category_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     category_comment GET    /categories/:category_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                      PATCH  /categories/:category_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                      PUT    /categories/:category_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                      DELETE /categories/:category_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
           categories GET    /categories(.:format)                                categories#index
                      POST   /categories(.:format)                                categories#create
         new_category GET    /categories/new(.:format)                            categories#new
        edit_category GET    /categories/:id/edit(.:format)                       categories#edit
             category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)                            categories#show
                      PATCH  /categories/:id(.:format)                            categories#update
                      PUT    /categories/:id(.:format)                            categories#update
                      DELETE /categories/:id(.:format)                            categories#destroy
           pages_home GET    /pages/home(.:format)                                pages#home
                 root GET    /                                                    pages#home
```

Comment: Did you forget to save the routes.rb file?

Comment: Saved it 3 times

Comment: You're doing something very wrong as that routes file does not give that output. Check for slop errors (wrong file, wrong path, wrong git branch etc).

Comment: I suspect that's my text editor who somehow open the wrong file... I used to delete it and do it again and tadam: it works :D   Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Found it. It was a strange bug.. doesn't know if it from my text editor or whatever, but I copy the content of routes.rb, delete it, create a new routes.rb file and pasted the content, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

These resource routes aren't matching up with the output of 'rails routes' - have you changed the `routes.rb` file since you ran 'rails routes'? If your `routes.rb` looks like you say above, 'rails routes' should return something along the lines of the following (with 'documentations' instead of 'comments'):

```
    category_documentations GET /categories/:category_id/documentations(.:format) comments#index
    category_documentations POST /categories/:category_id/documentations(.:format) comments#create
    ...
```

Comment: This is my actual routes, I confirm that it never have comments route in it.  Everything is up to date, I double checked it when creating the question.